# jquery object with parentheses

Tags: jquery, json

I have the below code and when the data portion is returned one of the object items names is "COUNT(email)" but I can't access this when I do this.COUNT(email). How do you access an object that has () in its name?

```
retrieve_data(dataset, '', '2', function(data){
            $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(name1, value1){
                $.each(value1, function(name2, value2){
                    $('.show_info').append('<tr><td>'+this.email+'</td><td>'+this.COUNT(email)+'</td></tr>');
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Did you try `this['COUNT(email)']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
this['COUNT(email)'];
```